# Finding angle and radius. Geometry/Trig application

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am lost with this problem. Can I apply $\pi - 3\pi/5$ since it's $180$ degree (Idk). How can I use $r=34$ while I don't have the other sides?

Comment: The image link is broken

Comment: At least ensure before posting question that given link is working.

Comment: Hi OP! The idea here is that, given $\theta$ measured in radians, we have that $r\theta$ = arc length - that is to say, if you have a circle with radius $r$ and angle $\theta$, then the arc length of the pie-slice-shaped section subtended by angle $\theta$ will be $r$ times $\theta$.

Comment: So, for example, if you have $\theta = 1$ in radians, then the length of the arc, going along the circumference of the circle from one terminal point of the angle to the other, would be $r \cdot 1$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

Comment: So, 100 is the arc length. 100 = 34 * data ?

Comment: The inner track of the half circle is $\pi*34 > 100$ the but the runner only runs $\frac {\theta}{\pi}$ of it. So $\frac {\theta}{\pi}*\pi * 34 = 100$.  What is $\theta$?  The outer track of the half circle is $\pi*r > 100$ but he only runs $\frac {\frac 34\pi}{\pi}$ of it.  So $\frac {\frac 34\pi}{\pi}*\pi*r = 100$.  What is r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A worked solution for 100% marks, on part (a) only, but with explanations

You DO have the other sides! The best skill to have in a mathematics exam is strong English-to-algebra translation. One key phrase in the question is,

> the 200 meter-dash

The other essential clue is,

> Each runner has to run 100 meters along the curved section

In other words, they are given different starting positions to make the race fair. They have the same finish line.

So the question is really asking:

**How far (as an angle) around a circle of radius 34m is a curve length of 100m?**

If that resolves the difficulty and you're excited to finish the problem yourself, don't read on!

---

For clarity of thought, we'll find the angle in half-turns. They are almost always the most intuitive angular unit, to make your thinking (and the early stages of your algebra) much simpler.

Then, we will convert the answer into the unit of your choice.
I will provide examples for degrees and radians. Use whatever is expected at your particular level.

---

For the angle in half-turns, we simply need the distance that the sprinter runs *as a proportion of the curve length*.

```
Angle in half-turns = 100m / [length of curve]
                    = 100m / (π * 34m)

Simplest symbolic answer:
                    = 50 / 17π
```

Simple, huh?

I have been pedantic with my units here. If you're looking for the 'half-turns' unit it is hiding on the left of the equality. "In" often means "divided by" just as "of" often means "multiplied by".

To convert half-turns to radians, multiply by π:

```
Was:          Angle = 50/17π half-turns

This becomes...

Symbolic:     Angle = 50 / 17
Numeric:      Angle = 2.94 (3 s.f.)
```

To convert half-turns to degrees, multiply by 180 degrees:

```
Was:          Angle = 50/17π half-turns

This becomes...

Symbolic:     Angle = (9000 / 17π) degrees
Numeric:      Angle = 168.5 degrees (3 s.f.)
```

---

**Rather than solve parts (b) and (c) *for* you, I think it's more useful to explain my answer to (a) more, so that you can write similarly careful answers to them for yourself.**

First, I recommend that in mathematics (though not always in science), you should maintain symbolic accuracy in your workings whenever you can, regardless of which form of answer you give. In science, or when symbolic workings are not possible, you should still maintain calculator accuracy, and I also recommend telling the examiner by literally writing,

> Workings maintain calculator accuracy

since they cannot see this, unlike any symbolic workings.

---

Second, something you may be unclear on, even though the level of the paper suggests you should understand this.

It is entirely up to you whether to write the radians unit, or give a pure number as your answer. It turns out that angular units actually *are* pure numbers, and in particular, we have

```
radian = 1
```

You can simplify all your algebra *and* your thinking at once, by thinking in terms of a half-turn but saying "π radians" or simply "π" in its place.

You may be best advised to write the radians unit, depending on whether you expect the marker to know that it is permissible to omit it.

It certainly appears that whoever wrote those questions is aware. They omit radians themselves, and the part asking for an angle is the only one that *doesn't* remind you to include units.

---

Good luck with parts (b) and (c)!
I am well aware that you didn't ask for the more general advice, and I hope my verbosity didn't put you off.

Comment: **CONDENSED:** `Angle in half-turns = _100m / [length of curve] = 100m / (π * 34m) = 50/17π` **.:** `Angle = (50/17π)π = 50/17`

Answer (score 1):

The arc length is the angle times the radius.

a) $\theta=\frac{100}{34}$ radians

b) $r=\frac{100}{\frac{3\pi}4}$ meters

c) $d=\frac{5\pi}6(r-34)$ meters

Comment: The straight section is 100 but what about the curved section?

Comment: The curved section is forced by the angle and the radius to equal exactly 100.  That's how the angle offsets were determined.

Comment: @205D4: by trigonometry, $200 - 100 = 100$.

Answer (score 0):

The lenght of the half circle of the inner track is $\pi*34 \approx 106 > 100$.  But the runner only runs a portion of it.  He runs $X *\pi*34 = 100$ so $X = \frac {100}{34\pi}\approx 93.6\%$ of the circle.

So instead of running from the full angle of $\pi$ he ran at an angle that is approximately only $93.6\%$ of $\pi$.

To be exact he ran at $X*\pi = \frac{100}{34\pi}*\pi = \frac {100}{34}$ radians.  In degrees this is $\approx .936*180 = 168.5$ degrees.)

Runner two and the outside track.  The length of the half circle of the outer track is $\pi*r > 100$.  But she only ran a portion of it.  The portion is $3/4$ of $\pi$.  So she ran $\frac 34\pi*r = 100$.  So $r = 100*\frac {4}{3\pi}\approx 42.4$ meters.

If the both had an offset of $\frac 56\pi$ the first runner would rund $\frac 56*\pi*34=\frac {85}3\pi$ meters.  Then second runner would have run $\frac 56*\pi*r = \frac 56*\pi*(100*\frac 4{3\pi})=\frac{1000}9$ meters.  So runner 2 runs $\frac{1000}9- \frac {85}3\pi$ more meters.